# Get QTableView cell value when pressing tab or enter key

Tags: python, events, keyboard, pyqt5, qtableview

I want to get the value of the cell of a `QTableView` when the user presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> or when the user puts a value into the cell and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: view GUI image here]

So I wrote the following code - but only I get the value when I click in the cell, not when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```py
    def table_config(self):
        setHeaders = ("CANTIDAD", "UNIDAD", "DESCRIPCION", "PRECIO UNITARIO", "PRECIO TOTAL")
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(setHeaders)
        self.tableWidget.wordWrap()
        self.tableWidget.alternatingRowColors()
        self.tableWidget.clicked.connect(self.dataCell)

    def dataCell(self, item):
        data = item.data() # I got the value of the cell only when i clicked in it.
        print(data)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Also, please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577) and [ask].

Comment: Ok, I‘ll do it, I’m really new in this kind of foros, or kind of app. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to override the keyPressEvent method and filter by the key pressed:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class TableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        if event.key() in (
            QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab,
            QtCore.Qt.Key_Return,
            QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter,
        ):
            it = self.currentItem()
            print(it)
            if it is not None:
                print(it.text())


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.tableWidget = TableWidget(6, 6)

        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(2):
                it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("{}-{}".format(i, j))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, it)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLineEdit())
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QSpinBox())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```